# Contradiction - equal entities are not equal

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

Please have a look at the fragment of kotlin tornadofx code:

```kotlin
println(costTable[1].numberGoodProperty)
println(SimpleIntegerProperty(objC.number))
val max11 = if (costTable[1].numberGoodProperty == SimpleIntegerProperty(objC.number)) 1 else 0
println("max11 $max11")
```

And this is the printout:

IntegerProperty [value: 2]

IntegerProperty [value: 2]

max11 0

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see `SimpleIntegerProperty` doesn't have the appropriate `equals` method so it uses `Object.equals` which just compares links to the objects. You have two distinct links so they are not equal